# How to implement lookaheads in Lark?

Tags: lark-parser

I'm currently looking at the work done to write the Python 3.8 grammar with Lark, and I'm wondering how that can be done with the Python 3.9 grammar specification which looks a bit simpler to me. Note that I'm not sure of whether my approach described below is correct or not.

In the Python 3.9 grammar specification, we have rules that use a negative lookahead like this one:

```
named_expression:
    | NAME ':=' ~ expression 
    | expression !':='    <--- This rule
```

I've tried to use a regex to define this negative lookahead like this:

```
negative_lookahead: /(?!:=)/
```

But it generates the following exception: `LexError: Lexer does not allow zero-width terminals.` Is there a way to define lookaheads with Lark?